# Any tricks to Doxygen formatting?

Tags: doxygen

Are there any tricks to allow my Doxygen generation to have a left-handed adjustment to certain text without having to edit the HTML after every update?

Comment: You should never touch the generated HTML. Think of it as the equivalent of modifying an object file generated by a compiler. Doxygen provides markdown, and if that isn't good enough, doxygen provides some HTML commands you can embed in your commentary: https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/htmlcmds.html .

Comment: doxygen has also possibilities to to something with the css it uses.